# Using of half or halve

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I'm ordering what's the difference between half and halve.

Example: Do I say

> When looking after their eggs, male penguins do not eat anything and loses **half/halve** their weight

Answer (score 5):

> male penguins do not eat anything and lose **half** their weight
>   male penguins do not eat anything and **halve** their weight

both sentences means half of the body mass of the penguin is lost through not eating.

**Halve** is the verb.

Answer (score 1):

*To halve* is the "verb form" of *half*, which can be a noun or modifier.  Consequently *half* is never used as a verb.

> ... male penguins do not eat anything, and lose half their weight.

Note that *halve* often means *to cut/break in half* or *to cut/break in 2 pieces*.  It's usually not used where *shrink* or *lose* would work.  For example, *I shrunk down to half size* is what to say, not *my size was halved.*